# Dynamic Memory Allocation with pointer arrays

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, malloc

I am trying to learn C from tutorials on the web, and I came up with this simple code to try and understand memory allocation on pointers and arrays.

The code compiles and runs flawlessly if `size` <= 2, but if `size` > 2 it gives a segmentation error. Can someone please shed a light on how to do this properly?

Thank you.

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main () {


int i, size;

printf("Quantos registos pretende inserir? ");
scanf("%d",&size);
getc(stdin);

typedef struct {
    char nome[81];
    int idade;
    char cargo[81];
} Dados;

Dados *data[(size-1)];

data[(size-1)] = (Dados *)malloc(sizeof(Dados));


for(i=0;i<size;i++) {
    printf("\nInsira os dados do funcionário: ");
    printf("\n\n\tNome: ");
    gets(data[i]->nome);
    printf("\n\tIdade: ");
    scanf("%d",&data[i]->idade);
    getc(stdin);
    printf("\n\tCargo: ");
    gets(data[i]->cargo);

    FILE *fdados;
    if(!(fdados = fopen("dados.txt","a+"))) {
         printf("Impossivel aceder ao ficheiro, verfique o erro ocorrido ...");
    }

    fprintf(fdados, "Funcionário %d:",(i+1));
    fprintf(fdados, "\n\n\tNome: %s",data[i]->nome);
    fprintf(fdados, "\n\tIdade: %d",data[i]->idade);
    fprintf(fdados, "\n\tCargo: %s\n\n",data[i]->cargo);

    fclose(fdados);

}

free(data[(size-1)]);

fflush(stdin);
return(0);
}
```

Comment: Please don't use the word "flawless". The only thing it means is that you have no idea what you're doing. Your code isn't flawless at all, but a horrible car crash for *any* value of `size, since `data[size - 1]` is *always* an out-of-bounds error, since the array is always one element shorter.

Comment: (This isn't even considering that variable-length arrays must have strictly positive size, and that `size` is signed and may well be negative, and that you don't allocate any memory for the bulk of the array elements.)

Comment: You are right, poor choice of words. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're giving yourself way too much to do in one go. Break the problem down and *test* each component:

1. Parse user input: Produce either a valid `size_t` integer or abort. Check that the value is neither zero nor too large, or abort.
2. Suppose you've parsed the value `n`. Allocate memory for `n` copies of your structure:

   ```
   Dados * data = malloc(n * sizeof(Dados));
   ```

   At the end, release the memory:

   ```
   free(data);
   ```
3. Use proper parsing with error handling to populate each array member `data[i]`.
4. Practice file operations separately.

Comment: Thank you very much, trying to learn from the web can sometimes be hard if you can't find a friendly answer to point you in the right direction. Code is running without segmentation problems

Comment: @tz0r: That doesn't mean that the code is correct, and it definitely isn't robust. You should always make every part of the code (especially the user input!) well defined and check return values of everything that could possibly fail.

Answer (score 1):

Well you have a struct, and it seems like you want to create multiple copies of that struct in an array.  So what you do is this

```
Dados *data;
data = (Dados *) malloc(sizeof(Dados) * size);
```

now you have size number of Dados structures located in data.

then at the end make sure to free your memory
    free(data);

Answer (score 0):

remove : `getc(stdin);`

```
Dados *data[(size-1)];

data[(size-1)] = (Dados *)malloc(sizeof(Dados));// here is wrong . 
                                                  you have data[size-1]
                                             the max index you can use is size-2



for(i=0;i<size;i++) // i < size-1 , since you use data[i] in loop ,

free(data[(size-1)]); // free (data);  just free the pointer you get.
```